# read data matrix with python in raspberry pi using pylibdmtx package

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm using libdmtx to decode data matrix with rasbian OS. when i run my code in windows, i get perfect results but in linux it does'nt work.
here is my simple code, when i run it in linux the variable "code" is always empty. i dont have any error. what is the problem?

```
import cv2 
import time
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import decode

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

while True:
    ret,img = cap.read()
    
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    t0 = time.time()
    code = decode(img, timeout=100, max_count=1, corrections=3)
    if(code):
        print((time.time() - t0)*1000)
        print(code)
        print(code[0].data.decode('utf-8'))
        print(code[0].rect)    
        #x,y,w,h = code[0].rect
        #cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,480-y-h),(255,0,255),2)
        
    cv2.imshow('Result',img)    
        
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Are the same libraries installed in both environments?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you've installed libdmtx on Linux:

From the repository's readme:
"The libdmtx DLLs are included with the Windows Python wheels. On other operating systems, you will need to install the libdmtx shared library."

That'd be my first guess.

Comment: You should edit your answer. Don't say that it's your guess and please provide procedure so other people with same problem can quickly apply your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 code = decode(img, timeout=100, max_count=1, corrections=3)
```

the timeout is to low. Try without timeout

```
code = decode(img, max_count=1, corrections=3)
```